# Use the same view inside a collectionViewCell and tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I created a nib file with a custom collectionViewCell and attached to a viewController

```
class CustomCollectionView: UICollectionViewCell{}
```

Now I have to use the exact cell inside a tableView. I created a new nib file and viewController

```
class CustomTableView: UITableViewCell{}
```

and I copied the hole code of `CustomCollectionView` on it. every thing is working fine but I believe that it dose not make sense to copy the hole exact code of `CustomCollectionView` into `CustomTableView` and to use the exact same nib file but with a `tableViewCell` instead of `collectionViewCell` on it. Is there any way to optimize what  I did?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in a comment in suhit's answer, you can do this by using a common view in both the `CollectionViewCell` and `TableViewCell` subclasses. You don't need a ViewController since it adds extra overhead. A simple UIView is enough. Some code to show what I mean:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var customView: CustomView!

    func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        customView = CustomView()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(customView)
        customView.fillSuperview()
    }
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var customView: CustomView!

    func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        customView = CustomView()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(customView)
        customView.fillSuperview()
    }
}


extension UIView {

    func fillSuperview() {
        guard let superview = superview else {
            return print("no superview")
        }
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentVisuperviewew.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}
```

A sample implementation for the `CustomView` class:

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    func initialize() {
        //...
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

}
```

If you wish to create your custom view in a xib that's also fine, but it's a little trickier. This is beyond the scope of the question but I'm just going to leave a link [here](https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960) in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same view then its better to use similar type view i.e. use collectionView at both places so that you can use the `CustomCollectionViewCell` in both `ViewControllers`. `UICollectionView` is highly customisable so you can do whatever you want to do with `UITableView` in `UICollectionView` as well.

Comment: Changing the tableView to a collectionView is not an option for me. Is it maybe a better idea to create the view as a UIViewController, and then load it inside the cells?

Comment: using the collection view cell will remove lot of duplicate code you need to write, it trivial to replace since you are using xib to create your custom cell. This approach seems better to me than creating a common view.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you. You mean using the collectionViewCell inside a tableView? did this work? or you mean using two  collectionView and not a tableView? As I said, I am working on an exsiting project and the second option is not possible

Comment: 'using the collectionViewCell inside a tableView' - NO, 'using two collectionView and not a tableView' - YES. if the functionality is same then I don't see any issue replacing the tableview with collectionView, choice is yours. Cheers.

Comment: The functionality is not the same at all and that's why I am using a table view. But only one cell is identical ...